# how to use angular filter filter keypress characters

Tags: parsing, angularjs, filter

http://jsfiddle.net/x3azn/s7gFD/1/

I have a filter that filters user input, but once every three times or twice, if you type a letter in the box, it would go through. try typing the following if you dont' understand what I mean.

```
ddd
asdfgg
vckzvdd
qwertt
```

hopefully u get the message.
and it wont appear ifyou type

```
dfadfasdf,
```

which is good but we cannot assume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parser is, for some reason, not executed on duplicate key presses.  So if you type "aa" or "bb" or "cc", you end up with "a", or "b", or "c" left in the box with the parser having never run.  I can't really answer why that's happening, but I can suggest an alternative:

Is there a reason you're coupling a filter with this directive?  You can just as easily accomplish the same task with the directive alone, and (to me anyway) it seems cleaner:

```
app.directive('filteredInput', function($filter){
    var dirLink = function(s,e,a,c){
        console.log(s);
        console.log(a);
        s.$watch(a.ngModel, function(v) {
            //if (pattern.indexOf('numbers') != -1){
               s[a.ngModel] = s[a.ngModel].replace(/[^\d.]/g, "");
           //}
        });
    }
    return{
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: true,
        link: dirLink
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s7gFD/2/

Comment: yeah I planeed on reusing this piece of code for many other fields, although this can be done using a service. I am also wondering if its possible to filter out spaces this way.